# Is it possible to retrieve the number of the option chosen in a form-control through the change listener?

Tags: angular, html, css, bootstrap-4

This is the custom cell renderer definition:

> drop-down-cell-renderer.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-drop-down-cell-renderer',
  templateUrl: './drop-down-cell-renderer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drop-down-cell-renderer.component.css']
})
export class DropDownCellRendererComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
 params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  public RefreshRisqueBrutColumn() {
    console.log('LISTENER WORKS')
  }
}
```

> drop-down-cell-renderer.component.html

```
<select class="form-control"  (change)=" RefreshRisqueBrutColumn();">
    <br>
    <option>1- Très improbable</option>
    <option>2- Peu probable</option>
    <option>3- Possible</option>
    <option>4- Probable</option>
</select>
```

[image]
What I would like to do is: 
Retrieve and log the number of the option chosen in a form-control through the change listener.
I.e:
User chooses option 0: the console will log: 0
User chooses option 1: the console will log: 1
And so on and so forth.
I am wondering whether I can do this natively. Or I have to write some extra code in the typescript file.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `$event` in your function call, and the use `$event.target.value` like so:

`RefreshRisqueBrutColumn($event);`

```
public RefreshRisqueBrutColumn(event) {
    console.log('LISTENER WORKS', event.target.value)
  }
```

Comment: No that would give me the actual option text not its number. Got it?

Comment: @AhmedGhrib you will need to move those options into an array, then use ngFor and there you can use  `i=index` and pass it to you function